# PHP infinite loop retrieving sql data to a html table

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a question on how I could "stop" this infinite loop to retrieve only 1 line of every SQL
row, not infinite rows.

Here is my code:

```
$consulta1 = "select * from productes where idCategoria = 1";

$resultado1 = $connexio->consultar($consulta1);

$reg1 = $connexio->obtenirRegistres($resultado1);

function tablaverdura($reg1)
{
    echo "<table>";
    while ($row = $reg1){
    echo "<tr><td>". $row['codProd'] . "</td><td>" . $row['nom']. "</td><td>". $row['descripcio']. "`enter code here`</td><td>". $row['pes']. "</td><td>". $row['stock']. "</td><td>". $row['idCategoria']. "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

i insert the function tablaverdura to the html.

Also the functons consultar and obtenirregistres is:

```
    function consultar($sentenciSql) {
        return $this->connexio->query($sentenciSql);
    }


    function obtenirRegistres($consulta) {
        return $consulta->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }
```

to fetch array and do the query.

The result is infinite ->   100 forquilla   per tallar  1   99  1

I just want one row, not infinite rows exactly the same as the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The loop is infinite because you never change `$reg1` in the loop. It's always just the first row that `obtenirRegistres()` returned.

You need to call `obtenirRegistres()` in the loop to fetch each row.

```
$consulta1 = "select * from productes where idCategoria = 1";

$resultado1 = $connexio->consultar($consulta1);

tablaverdura($resultado1);

function tablaverdura($resultado1)
{
    echo "<table>";
    while ($row = $connexio->obtenirRegistres($resultado1)){
        echo "<tr><td>". $row['codProd'] . "</td><td>" . $row['nom']. "</td><td>". $row['descripcio']. "`enter code here`</td><td>". $row['pes']. "</td><td>". $row['stock']. "</td><td>". $row['idCategoria']. "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}
```